# Getting an error "Will attempt to recover by breaking" not on simulator but on iPhone

Tags: swift, swift2

After changing the way for making the TableView to the one uses xib file, I've been getting an error in the next view. The error says "Will attempt to recover by breaking" while moving to the next view.
The weird thing is that I don't get that error when using a simulator and it occurs only on real iPhone.

FirstView.swift

```
func onMessageBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {
        if didTransition == false{
            didTransition = true
            self.delegate._selectedProjectId = sender.tag
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let nextVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GroupsViewController")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

And

in the Log

```
 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    NSLayoutConstraint:0x16fbc630 V:[UIView:0x16fcf570(57)]
    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
    2016-05-11 18:22:42.870 APP-NAME[376:30474] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1a894b10 V:[UIView:0x1a881d60(57)]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16f99bc0 UIView:0x1a881d60.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x16fc2cc0.topMargin + 71>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16f99bf0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x16fc2cc0.bottomMargin == UIView:0x1a881d60.bottom + 13>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1a8999a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x16fc2cc0(129.5)]>"
    )
```

Please check the constraints below:

[The constraints in AutoLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su4bS.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not much we can except tell you: recheck every constraint. You probably have some set in a way that works on the simulator resolution but breaks on your device since it probably has a different resolution. Have you tried to run it on the same simulator type as the real actual device?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestion. I've tried to run it on the same simulator type as the real actual device and it worked well. I understood if it was occurred on that simulator. Maybe still it's a problem about the constraints but I wonder why it's happening only after changing the way of making TableView.. It was working well..

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. The first step is to identify the constraint or constraints causing the conflict. This can be done by giving them labels so that the error output become a bit more readable, but I usually find it easier to delete constraints until the error goes away and then hit undo. Once you have found the offending constraint, reduce it's priority from 1000 to 999 and that should fix it. This has worked a few times for me, doesn't change the layout and clears the error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it later, and tell you how it's worked!